# What is causing this Kernel Panic (GPU Panic)?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, crash, kernel-panic

My MacBook Pro keeps crashing. I can find no pattern to what causes it. Sometimes it goes for a day without crashing. Sometimes it crashes repeatedly.

I've run an Apple Hardware Test (holding down D on startup) and no problems are found. I have also reset the NVRAM and repaired disk and permissions.

Can anyone see anything here that might suggest what is causing these crashes?

```
Interval Since Last Panic Report:  6093 sec
Panics Since Last Report:          1
Anonymous UUID:                    0E9BBD0F-47AF-70B3-6785-81A8D2D7FEA5

Thu Mar 13 20:39:32 2014
panic(cpu 4 caller 0xffffff7f859cff1a): "GPU Panic: [<None>] 3 0 a0 d9 9 8 0 3 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00000100: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0x103000000 0xffffff81d7b65000 0x0e7150a2, D0, P1/4\n"@/SourceCache/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.4.5/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:127
Backtrace (CPU 4), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81d4fa3590 : 0xffffff800361d636
0xffffff81d4fa3600 : 0xffffff7f859cff1a
0xffffff81d4fa36d0 : 0xffffff7f83e2c26c
0xffffff81d4fa3790 : 0xffffff7f83eff1f6
0xffffff81d4fa37d0 : 0xffffff7f83eff254
0xffffff81d4fa3840 : 0xffffff7f8421f6fe
0xffffff81d4fa38b0 : 0xffffff7f83f27ad1
0xffffff81d4fa38d0 : 0xffffff7f83e3303f
0xffffff81d4fa3980 : 0xffffff7f83e30ad6
0xffffff81d4fa3b80 : 0xffffff7f83e31b41
0xffffff81d4fa3c60 : 0xffffff7f83dced02
0xffffff81d4fa3df0 : 0xffffff7f83dcda8c
0xffffff81d4fa3e10 : 0xffffff7f859919e0
0xffffff81d4fa3ef0 : 0xffffff7f859918cf
0xffffff81d4fa3f40 : 0xffffff7f85990783
0xffffff81d4fa3f60 : 0xffffff800363e26e
0xffffff81d4fa3fb0 : 0xffffff80036b3257 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.4.5)[49FEF732-D7A3-327B-A7AA-6AC5A6E3DCFF]@0xffffff7f859c2000->0xffffff7f859d4fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert(1.0.4)[B5B1F368-132E-3509-9ED5-93270E3ABBDD]@0xffffff7f859bd000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.8)[2FAEA49C-EA4C-39C6-9203-FC022277A43C]@0xffffff7f83c4d000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.4.5)[4A2C8548-7EF1-38A9-8817-E8CB34B8DCA6]@0xffffff7f859a9000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[A35915E8-C1B0-3C0F-81DF-5515BC9002FC]@0xffffff7f847c1000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.3.7)[F16E015E-1ABE-3C40-AC71-BC54F4BE442E]@0xffffff7f83db7000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.7)[9928306E-3508-3DBC-80A4-D8F1D87650D7]@0xffffff7f83d74000
         com.apple.NVDAResman(8.1.6)[EA4F9902-5AAE-3F1D-A846-3796221C8C91]@0xffffff7f83dcb000->0xffffff7f8406dfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.8)[2FAEA49C-EA4C-39C6-9203-FC022277A43C]@0xffffff7f83c4d000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.3.7)[F16E015E-1ABE-3C40-AC71-BC54F4BE442E]@0xffffff7f83db7000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.7)[9928306E-3508-3DBC-80A4-D8F1D87650D7]@0xffffff7f83d74000
         com.apple.nvidia.gk100hal(8.1.6)[A6140B32-E6F2-37A2-94A1-D957086A854E]@0xffffff7f84079000->0xffffff7f843a8fff
            dependency: com.apple.NVDAResman(8.1.6)[EA4F9902-5AAE-3F1D-A846-3796221C8C91]@0xffffff7f83dcb000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.8)[2FAEA49C-EA4C-39C6-9203-FC022277A43C]@0xffffff7f83c4d000
         com.apple.driver.AGPM(100.13.12)[40BECF44-B2F1-3933-8074-AD07B38CA43A]@0xffffff7f8598f000->0xffffff7f859a0fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.8)[2FAEA49C-EA4C-39C6-9203-FC022277A43C]@0xffffff7f83c4d000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily(5.4.1d13)[04F9C88C-92F3-300B-8C68-4A0B5F7D8C94]@0xffffff7f847ca000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.3.7)[F16E015E-1ABE-3C40-AC71-BC54F4BE442E]@0xffffff7f83db7000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.7)[9928306E-3508-3DBC-80A4-D8F1D87650D7]@0xffffff7f83d74000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
12F45

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 12.5.0: Sun Sep 29 13:33:47 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2050.48.12~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: EA38B02E-2B88-309F-BA68-1DE29F605DD8
Kernel slide:     0x0000000003400000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8003600000
System model name: MacBookPro10,1 (Mac-C3EC7CD22292981F)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 6392616346435
last loaded kext at 3397288226703: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver    237.1 (adde 0xffffff7f85b30000, size 12288)
last unloaded kext at 3476654288443: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC   4.1.23 (addr 0xffffff7f85b2b000, size 12288)

loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  4.2.6
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  4.2.6
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 4.2.6
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 4.2.6
com.rogueamoeba.InstantOnCore   6.0.3
com.rogueamoeba.InstantOn   6.0.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothSCOAudioDriver  4.1.7f2
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothA2DPAudioDriver 4.1.7f2
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.13.12
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler 2.0.7d2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.1.7f2
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.4.7fc4
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.4.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.12
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.1.7f4
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.4.7fc4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   8.1.6
com.apple.GeForce   8.1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.11d1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.6.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.4.5
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 8.1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.1.11
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.3d0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  237.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 237.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 34 com.apple.driver.XsanFilter  404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.3.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    635.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.4.3
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   615.20.17
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.6.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   621.4.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   635.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 214.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   4.0.39
com.apple.security.quarantine   2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   214.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.6
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.4.7fc4
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   86.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.1.7f2
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.9.2fc7
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.12
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.1.7f2
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily 74.15
com.apple.nvidia.gk100hal   8.1.6
com.apple.NVDAResman    8.1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.4.7fc4
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.4.7fc4
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.4.5
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.11d1
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.7
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.7
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.5d4
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.4.1d13
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.5.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    2.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    2.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 1.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 237.3
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  623.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   621.4.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  621.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    1.9.2
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 2.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   530.5
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 630.4.4
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.5.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 635.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.8.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  220.3
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 345
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  28.21
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.8
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro10,1, BootROM MBP101.00EE.B02, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.6 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.3f36
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In, 512 MB Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D5434314753364D465238432D50422020 Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D5434314753364D465238432D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xEF), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.17) Bluetooth: Version 4.1.7f2 12718, 3 service, 21 devices, 3 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM512E, 500.28 GB
USB Device: hub_device, 0x8087  (Intel Corporation), 0x0024, 0x1a100000 / 2
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in), apple_vendor_id, 0x8510, 0x1a110000 / 3
USB Device: hub_device, 0x8087  (Intel Corporation), 0x0024, 0x1d100000 / 2
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2512, 0x1d180000 / 3
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0x1d181000 / 5
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x8286, 0x1d181300 / 7
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0263, 0x1d182000 / 4
```

And here is a second Crash Report:

```
Interval Since Last Panic Report:  2208 sec
Panics Since Last Report:          1
Anonymous UUID:                    0E9BBD0F-47AF-70B3-6785-81A8D2D7FEA5

Thu Mar 13 21:30:47 2014
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff7f91fcff1a): "GPU Panic: [<None>] 3 0 a0 d9 9 8 0 3 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00000144: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0x103000000 0xffffff81e41d5000 0x0e7150a2, D0, P2/4\n"@/SourceCache/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.4.5/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:127
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81d1d25bf0 : 0xffffff800fc1d636 
0xffffff81d1d25c60 : 0xffffff7f91fcff1a 
0xffffff81d1d25d30 : 0xffffff7f9042c26c 
0xffffff81d1d25df0 : 0xffffff7f904ff1f6 
0xffffff81d1d25e30 : 0xffffff7f908142f3 
0xffffff81d1d25e50 : 0xffffff7f90432f56 
0xffffff81d1d25ef0 : 0xffffff7f903d0dae 
0xffffff81d1d25f10 : 0xffffff8010053298 
0xffffff81d1d25f40 : 0xffffff7f9026428b 
0xffffff81d1d25f50 : 0xffffff7f9204c533 
0xffffff81d1d25f60 : 0xffffff7f9205420b 
0xffffff81d1d25f80 : 0xffffff800fcb7f7c 
0xffffff81d1d25fd0 : 0xffffff800fccedbb 
0xffffff81f7e1bdb0 : 0xffffff800fc2f35d 
0xffffff81f7e1bdf0 : 0xffffff800fc2de11 
0xffffff81f7e1be50 : 0xffffff800fc2db83 
0xffffff81f7e1be90 : 0xffffff800ffbdbec 
0xffffff81f7e1bf50 : 0xffffff800ffe97ba 
0xffffff81f7e1bfb0 : 0xffffff800fccf453 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.8)[2FAEA49C-EA4C-39C6-9203-FC022277A43C]@0xffffff7f9024d000->0xffffff7f90275fff
         com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform(1.8)[209B2382-A61F-344C-8BBC-26331B9BA398]@0xffffff7f92045000->0xffffff7f9209efff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[A35915E8-C1B0-3C0F-81DF-5515BC9002FC]@0xffffff7f90dc1000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.8)[2FAEA49C-EA4C-39C6-9203-FC022277A43C]@0xffffff7f9024d000
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.4.5)[49FEF732-D7A3-327B-A7AA-6AC5A6E3DCFF]@0xffffff7f91fc2000->0xffffff7f91fd4fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert(1.0.4)[B5B1F368-132E-3509-9ED5-93270E3ABBDD]@0xffffff7f91fbd000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.8)[2FAEA49C-EA4C-39C6-9203-FC022277A43C]@0xffffff7f9024d000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.4.5)[4A2C8548-7EF1-38A9-8817-E8CB34B8DCA6]@0xffffff7f91fa9000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[A35915E8-C1B0-3C0F-81DF-5515BC9002FC]@0xffffff7f90dc1000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.3.7)[F16E015E-1ABE-3C40-AC71-BC54F4BE442E]@0xffffff7f903b7000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.7)[9928306E-3508-3DBC-80A4-D8F1D87650D7]@0xffffff7f90374000
         com.apple.NVDAResman(8.1.6)[EA4F9902-5AAE-3F1D-A846-3796221C8C91]@0xffffff7f903cb000->0xffffff7f9066dfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.8)[2FAEA49C-EA4C-39C6-9203-FC022277A43C]@0xffffff7f9024d000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.3.7)[F16E015E-1ABE-3C40-AC71-BC54F4BE442E]@0xffffff7f903b7000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.7)[9928306E-3508-3DBC-80A4-D8F1D87650D7]@0xffffff7f90374000
         com.apple.nvidia.gk100hal(8.1.6)[A6140B32-E6F2-37A2-94A1-D957086A854E]@0xffffff7f90679000->0xffffff7f909a8fff
            dependency: com.apple.NVDAResman(8.1.6)[EA4F9902-5AAE-3F1D-A846-3796221C8C91]@0xffffff7f903cb000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.8)[2FAEA49C-EA4C-39C6-9203-FC022277A43C]@0xffffff7f9024d000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: CrashPlanService

Mac OS version:
12F45

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 12.5.0: Sun Sep 29 13:33:47 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2050.48.12~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: EA38B02E-2B88-309F-BA68-1DE29F605DD8
Kernel slide:     0x000000000fa00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff800fc00000
System model name: MacBookPro10,1 (Mac-C3EC7CD22292981F)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 11916535527
last loaded kext at 7860874725: org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  4.2.6 (addr 0xffffff7f92122000, size 28672)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  4.2.6
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  4.2.6
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 4.2.6
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 4.2.6
com.rogueamoeba.InstantOnCore   6.0.3
com.rogueamoeba.InstantOn   6.0.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothSCOAudioDriver  4.1.7f2
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothA2DPAudioDriver 4.1.7f2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.1.7f2
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.0.7d2
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.13.12
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   2.4.7fc4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU   4.1.7f2
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.4.7fc4
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.4.7fc4
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.1.7f4
com.apple.GeForce   8.1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   8.1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.12
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.11d1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.6.3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 8.1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.3d0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.3.5
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.1.11
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.4.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.4.5
com.apple.nvidia.NVDAStartup    8.1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  237.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   237.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 237.1
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 34
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.3.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    635.4.0
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   615.20.17
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.4.3
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.6.2b4
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.6.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   621.4.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   635.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 214.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   4.0.39
com.apple.security.quarantine   2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   214.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.6
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.5.6
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.4.7fc4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.1.7f2
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily 74.15
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.nvidia.gk100hal   8.1.6
com.apple.NVDAResman    8.1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   2.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.11d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.4.1d13
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.4.7fc4
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.4.7fc4
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   86.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.1.7f2
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.9.2fc7
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.12
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.5d4
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.4.5
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.7
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 237.3
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  623.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    2.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    2.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 1.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   621.4.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  621.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    1.9.2
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 2.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   530.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 630.4.4
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.2b1
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.5.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 635.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.8.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  220.3
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 345
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  28.21
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.8
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro10,1, BootROM MBP101.00EE.B02, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.6 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.3f36
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In, 512 MB
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D5434314753364D465238432D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D5434314753364D465238432D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xEF), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.17)
Bluetooth: Version 4.1.7f2 12718, 3 service, 21 devices, 3 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM512E, 500.28 GB
USB Device: hub_device, 0x8087  (Intel Corporation), 0x0024, 0x1a100000 / 2
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in), apple_vendor_id, 0x8510, 0x1a110000 / 3
USB Device: hub_device, 0x8087  (Intel Corporation), 0x0024, 0x1d100000 / 2
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2512, 0x1d180000 / 3
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0263, 0x1d182000 / 5
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0x1d181000 / 4
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x8286, 0x1d181300 / 7
```

Comment: @grgarside Apologies. Fixed now.

Comment: Still not quite right — Quote formatting strips the line breaks so using code formatting on previously-quoted text doesn't really work and makes you scroll horizontally forever. Could you format with code the original text?

Comment: @grgarside I removed the quotes and then formatted it for code, but something not right. Added a break. That's the best I can do.

Comment: I've attempted to fix the formatting manually — in the future please paste the log in verbatim then use code formatting.

Comment: @grgarside Added a second report. Copied straight from the crash reporter. Formatting is wrong.

Comment: The formatting seems perfectly preserved this time… I forgot to format a bit of the first one — fixed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Constant kernel GPU panics (GPUPanic.cpp:127) on mid-2010 MacBook Pro (6,2)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130933/constant-kernel-gpu-panics-gpupanic-cpp127-on-mid-2010-macbook-pro-6-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out my motherboard needed replacing. Thank the gods it was still under Apple Care.