# Constant kernel GPU panics (GPUPanic.cpp:127) on mid-2010 MacBook Pro (6,2)

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, crash, kernel-panic, gpu

Hardware is a mid 2010 MAcBook Pro 15", i7 2,66ghz, 8 GB RAM, 512 MB Video RAM.

I encounter regular kernel panics for a while now, I think since upgrading to Mavericks. Usually it used to happen every now and then, between once a week and once a month. So I did not really worry in the beginning. As it started getting on my nerves and neither volume repair nor hard ware test did indicate anything wrong, I decided to do a clean install of the latest Mavericks version a few days ago to see if that helps. kernel panics are still there and with the update to 10.9.3. today it seems even worse. I already had two kernel panics today, which make it four this week.

Attached is the latest kernel panic log:

```
Anonymous UUID:       2BA5E44A-7200-45C0-F925-7A3107857DDC

Fri May 16 14:19:00 2014
panic(cpu 3 caller 0xffffff7f8b041f7c): "GPU Panic: [<None>] 3 3 7f 0 0 0 0 3 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00000100: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0xd2000000 0xffffff8124ee6000 0x0a5480a2, D0, P2/4\n"@/SourceCache/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.5.26/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:127
Backtrace (CPU 3), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8113f4b140 : 0xffffff8008c22fa9 
0xffffff8113f4b1c0 : 0xffffff7f8b041f7c 
0xffffff8113f4b290 : 0xffffff7f89672e7b 
0xffffff8113f4b350 : 0xffffff7f8973c46a 
0xffffff8113f4b390 : 0xffffff7f8973c4da 
0xffffff8113f4b400 : 0xffffff7f899bb056 
0xffffff8113f4b530 : 0xffffff7f8975fb09 
0xffffff8113f4b550 : 0xffffff7f896798cd 
0xffffff8113f4b600 : 0xffffff7f896773d8 
0xffffff8113f4b800 : 0xffffff7f89678356 
0xffffff8113f4b8e0 : 0xffffff7f8a6699c2 
0xffffff8113f4b920 : 0xffffff7f8a67937f 
0xffffff8113f4b940 : 0xffffff7f8a6a733b 
0xffffff8113f4b980 : 0xffffff7f8a6a739b 
0xffffff8113f4b9c0 : 0xffffff7f8a67ee15 
0xffffff8113f4ba10 : 0xffffff7f8a64ab5e 
0xffffff8113f4baa0 : 0xffffff7f8a646ae7 
0xffffff8113f4bad0 : 0xffffff7f8a644636 
0xffffff8113f4bb00 : 0xffffff80090ce0a3 
0xffffff8113f4bb90 : 0xffffff80090cff9f 
0xffffff8113f4bbf0 : 0xffffff80090cdabf 
0xffffff8113f4bd40 : 0xffffff8008cb66a8 
0xffffff8113f4be50 : 0xffffff8008c26bf1 
0xffffff8113f4be80 : 0xffffff8008c139f5 
0xffffff8113f4bef0 : 0xffffff8008c1e043 
0xffffff8113f4bf70 : 0xffffff8008cc989d 
0xffffff8113f4bfb0 : 0xffffff8008cf3c76 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(8.2.4)[6EB3FF52-A4F6-3496-AE9C-D89B00FDE504]@0xffffff7f89623000->0xffffff7f8988bfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[244D4E48-78E6-3369-8D76-285C66EF9BF4]@0xffffff7f892be000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[B93BBFC9-9ED5-3DDD-8CED-5EDA081BB997]@0xffffff7f89613000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[B889D3AB-CCC0-3FCD-A83E-D2E3E4CB537B]@0xffffff7f895d0000
         com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla(8.2.4)[B0E6AAA7-E970-3D81-8B43-145D56A3A4AC]@0xffffff7f89896000->0xffffff7f89b3ffff
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(8.2.4)[6EB3FF52-A4F6-3496-AE9C-D89B00FDE504]@0xffffff7f89623000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[244D4E48-78E6-3369-8D76-285C66EF9BF4]@0xffffff7f892be000
         com.apple.GeForceTesla(8.2.4)[24ED915E-02F3-3A31-8502-6AA41FFCA420]@0xffffff7f8a629000->0xffffff7f8a6f3fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[244D4E48-78E6-3369-8D76-285C66EF9BF4]@0xffffff7f892be000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[B93BBFC9-9ED5-3DDD-8CED-5EDA081BB997]@0xffffff7f89613000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[B889D3AB-CCC0-3FCD-A83E-D2E3E4CB537B]@0xffffff7f895d0000
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(8.2.4)[6EB3FF52-A4F6-3496-AE9C-D89B00FDE504]@0xffffff7f89623000
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.5.26)[B67CD59F-1344-37BC-8A9A-46D6D3DCA13D]@0xffffff7f8b033000->0xffffff7f8b046fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.5.26)[C0F9A79F-167E-3A68-873C-5CE17B97FB11]@0xffffff7f8b02b000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[045D5D6F-AD1E-36DB-A249-A346E2B48E54]@0xffffff7f89578000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[244D4E48-78E6-3369-8D76-285C66EF9BF4]@0xffffff7f892be000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[B889D3AB-CCC0-3FCD-A83E-D2E3E4CB537B]@0xffffff7f895d0000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert(1.0.4)[E04639C5-D734-3AB3-A682-FE66694C6653]@0xffffff7f8b02e000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer

Mac OS version:
13D65

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 13.2.0: Thu Apr 17 23:03:13 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.100.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: ADD73AE6-88B0-32FB-A8BB-4F7C8BE4092E
Kernel slide:     0x0000000008a00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8008c00000
System model name: MacBookPro6,2 (Mac-F22586C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 4401259546857
last loaded kext at 3670375376124: com.apple.driver.AppleIntelMCEReporter   104 (addr 0xffffff7f8b144000, size 49152)
last unloaded kext at 3786700867221: com.apple.driver.AppleIntelMCEReporter 104 (addr 0xffffff7f8b144000, size 32768)
loaded kexts:
at.obdev.nke.LittleSnitch   4092
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   80.14
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.14.15
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.2.4f1
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.6.1f2
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.6.1f2
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.5.26
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.GeForceTesla  8.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.13
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.1.12
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphics   8.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphicsFB 8.2.4
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.2.4f1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.0
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  325.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.4.1
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.6.6
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    666.4.0
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   700.20.22
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.8.1b2
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   660.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 217.92.1
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   153
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   217.92.1
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.2.4f1
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  245.13
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.5.26
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.7
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   91.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.2.4f1
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.6.1f2
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.9.7fc2
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.14
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.5.26
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.11d1
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   8.2.4
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    8.2.4
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.2.4f1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.6.1f2
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.6.1f2
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.7.0d11
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireSerialBusProtocolTransport    2.5.1
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireSBP2  4.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 240.9
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  660.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.6.6
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   650.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  656.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.6.6
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.6.6
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 660.4.2
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   630.35
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b4
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b5
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.6.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 677.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  278.11
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 371.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  23
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
```

Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be or how to track it down? Might the video card or kernel extension be the problem? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hey Ben, did apple repair you Macbook with a new Logic Board for free?

Comment: Yes, they did. Though it took a few phone calls and several days from confirmation of the known GPU error before they finally agreed to replace for free.

Comment: Related: [OS X - GPU Panic](http://superuser.com/q/831617/87805) at SU.SE

Comment: I've been helping a friend with this same model of MacBook Pro who was having random reboots.  This thread was a huge help understanding what was going on.  I actually just upgraded him to El Capitan and truly haven't seen any issues since.  I've been pushing it pretty hard all day, randomly opening various apps, a lot once, etc.  I think there's a chance the issue is somehow fixed in El Capitan.  Will update if it starts acting up again...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes the GPU panics are almost certainly due to a defective discrete GPU card. I have the same 2010 MBP and have noticed 10.9.3 has increased the frequency of these fatal crashes significantly.

I'm using the [gfxCardStatus](http://gfx.io/) utility to turn off this discrete card whenever possible but many apps force it on.

Comment: I use the same program, but unfortunately can't disable discrete with an external monitor..

Comment: This series of laptops (2010-2011) with the discrete GPU have a known issue with the GPU that Apple seems perfectly happy not to do anything about - like a recall, or similar. There are many of them in the wild with defective GPU cards, but Apple is treating each occurrence as if they have never seen the problem before. I had a 2011 17" MBP that thankfully did NOT have the problem, but selling it second hand was surprisingly difficult, as the local shops all said they won't touch those models with a ten-foot pole. I guess the discrete GPU is just a case of "another thing to go wrong" ...

Comment: Replacing the Logic board was not an option for me and neither was it financially feasible. To extend on your answer, Gfx v1.8.1 is what fixed the issue for me permanently. I have answered the question here:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179825/question-about-gpu-panic-on-mid-2010-macbookpro6-2/304525#304525

We have a permanent software solution, and I think folks are going to be happy with it.

Answer (score 15):

Repeated kernel panics occurring without third party drivers can only be caused by a few things:

1) A peripheral device

2) A bad OSX image or bug in OSX itself

3) A hardware problem

In your case, it is unfortunately (3):

> *System model name: MacBookPro6,2*

The kernel panic indicates that your GPU is failing. *This is [a known issue](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-5681) for your machine.* Your model is subject to [a replacement program](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4088?) for the logicboard due to a defective GPU. It lasts 3 years from the date of purchase. If this is already expired, Apple may or may not still replace your logicboard. It is ultimately at the discretion of the store manager. If you don't qualify, your other option would be a flat rate repair, for ~$300, which Apple will repair anything wrong with the machine for this fee. Best of luck.

Comment: +1 I also suffer because of this for about half year now. Unfortunatelly It has begun after 3 years of purchase.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am just out of the 3 year since purchase...

Comment: I have had good luck with getting Apple to do the right thing on hardware a little past warranty expiry.

Comment: Both the Apple Store and Apple Support told me to shell out the cash because my 4 yr applecare warranty had just lapsed. I fear Apple has become the new Microsoft..

Answer (score 1):

After a few arguments with a local Apple Store I contacted national Apple management and argued that the problems only started after upgrading to Maverick, which happened three years after purchase. Since they never mentioned Maverick would cause problems on a 2010 MacBook Pro the replacement program should still be applied. They finally agreed.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has issued a recall for Macbook Pros Mid 2012. Others may be in the recall. I took it to a store and they had to replace the Logic board ($1000). Thankfully I did not have to pay a cent due to the recall. If you have "GPU Panic" based screen blanks, take it to Mac Shop/Repair shop and they will take care of it.  They will run a diagnostic and in 20 mins you will know if it is eligible.

This is not a software issue. Apple would have taken care of it that way. Reinstalling the OS is not an option.

This is a hardware issue. Logic board needs to be removed. Go to a mac store.

Read about the recall here: http://www.macworld.co.uk/news/mac/widespread-2011-macbook-pro-failures-petition-lawsuit-repair-programme-3497935/

Answer (score 0):

Seems like using the Kext Utility to clear and repair my kext permissions and doing a clean boot fixed this issue for me. Only tested for a few hours now but so far so good. Many people get a logic board replacement but I think it may have been a kext issue as every time I upgrade I run into kernel panics at some point. I push my machines to the limit and run into panics every 10 or so minutes when running on "Discrete GPU" only.

Now I can enable automatic switching without any problems. Hope this helps someone.

http://www.hackintoshosx.com/files/download/4286-kext-utility/

Answer (score -2):

Im surprised that nobody on any forums has even touched on this answer i'm about to give and i HAD the exact same issues with mine that most ppl have been having.. So heres what ive found is the root of mine and a few ppls computers ive fixed due to gpu panics.. If you have corrupt or unsupported .jpeg, .mpeg, .mp4, PDF, or any related formats on your hd, it will cause GPU panics to happen.. So the best way to figure it out before thinking that your GPU is fried is get Tech Tool Pro or a similar app and do a file optimization test. On TTP it will tell u which ones and exactly where they r located.. I made the mistake of "upgrading" from Mavericks to Yosemite, and it messed everything up.. I ended up with over 1000 unsupported or corrupt files in those formats because of the "upgrade". It took a couple of painstaking hours to remove the files manually, but the panics have virtually stopped.. And my panics where absolutely infuriating.. I would turn my computer on and if i ran more than 1 or 2 apps at once, it would double panic, then 10 minutes later, it would do it again out of nowhere.. So a simple thing like taking all of those corrupt files fixed it.. Im amazed that all those "support techs" or "gurus" that work for mac havent shed any light on this, because its kinda common sense that would be one of the first things they should be thinking of when troubleshooting this VERY common issue! Hope this helps! If it did, please leave a like or comment, so i can keep personal track myself of how many headaches this might help be avoiding! ;)

---

Use Tech Tool Pro or related software that has a **file optimization** feature and remove all corrupt or unsupported files that I listed above.

Comment: As written it's hard to understand what your actual answer is here. Future visitors probably are more interested in the steps you recommend to analyze/fix this than in your overall experience analyzing this. Could you try to turn your answer into more of a list of instructions on how to proceed?

Comment: Sorry, i thought it was clear... Use Tech Tool Pro or RELATED software that has a FILE OPTIMIZATION feature and REMOVE all CORRUPT or UNSUPPORTED files that i listed above. Does that clear things up?