# Macbook pro constantly crashing

Tags: macbook-pro, crash, kernel-panic

We have a Macbook Pro (see spec below) that consistently crashes, it can run for anything up to two hours but the crashing seems completely random within that time.

I've attached the spec and error message below, does anyone have any ideas of what it could be? Hardware or software?

We've run all available updates as well.

[image]

[image]

> Interval Since Last Panic Report: 200870 sec  Panics Since Last Report: 4  Anonymous UUID: 965EBA7B-13D1-4B15-9DC5-BC2C8A5E525C

```
> Sat Jun 21 11:03:18 2014  panic(cpu 3 caller 0x9d4c9b): NVRM[0/1:0:0]:
> Read Error 0x0061021c: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0
> 0xc0000000 0x7fcbc000 0x0a5480a2, D0, P3/4  Backtrace (CPU 3), Frame :
> Return Address (4 potential args on stack)  0x5c0620d8 : 0x21b837
> (0x5dd7fc 0x5c06210c 0x223ce1 0x0)  0x5c062128 : 0x9d4c9b (0xbea28c
> 0xc5a800 0xbf8e60 0x0)  0x5c0621c8 : 0xaef608 (0x8fea404 0x9a4b004
> 0x61021c 0x15fdf6a)  0x5c062218 : 0x1600ffe (0x9a4b004 0x61021c 0x0
> 0x0)  0x5c062298 : 0x9b0a9f (0x9a4b004 0x9a71004 0xc1d00041
> 0xbfef0034)  0x5c062378 : 0x9b11e3 (0xc1d00041 0xbfef0033 0xbfef0034
> 0x857c)  0x5c0623a8 : 0x9b697f (0x5c062438 0x5c0624ac 0x5c0623d8
> 0x2aa21d)  0x5c0623f8 : 0x9b6b3f (0xc1d00041 0x1 0x5c062458 0x9ccd45) 
> 0x5c062488 : 0x9b6c34 (0x857c 0x5c0627d0 0x0 0x0)  0x5c062518 :
> 0x9da65c (0x5c0626f8 0x9 0x0 0x0)  0x5c0626c8 : 0x9dc58f (0x0
> 0x600d600d 0x702b 0x5c0626f8)  0x5c062798 : 0xc9feae (0xc1d00041
> 0xbfef0033 0xbfef0034 0x857c)  0x5c062808 : 0xcaf734 (0x983f200
> 0x10fdbe80 0x8 0x2)  0x5c062828 : 0xcd4322 (0x10fdbe80 0xb 0x5c062848
> 0x0)  0x5c062858 : 0xcd4b3d (0x9ba0000 0x0 0x5c06287c 0x0)  0x5c062888
> : 0xcb4d79 (0x9ba0000 0x7d4ba080 0x0 0x2e3)  0x5c0628d8 : 0xc76d0c
> (0x46569000 0x0 0x0 0x3)  0x5c062948 : 0xc7640f (0x46569000 0x0 0x2
> 0x3)  0x5c062978 : 0xc6c05f (0x46569000 0x0 0x2 0x4631c000) 
> 0x5c062ab8 : 0xca55d8 (0x4631c000 0x1 0x5c062bcc 0x5c062bc8) 
> 0x5c062b68 : 0xc67fe1 (0x4631c000 0x1 0x5c062bcc 0x5c062bc8) 
> 0x5c062be8 : 0x56da06 (0x4631c000 0x0 0x5c062e3c 0x5c062c74) 
> 0x5c062c38 : 0x56e2a5 (0xcf6720 0x4631c000 0x9e38688 0x1)  0x5c062c88
> : 0x56eb59 (0x4631c000 0x10 0x5c062cd0 0x0)  0x5c062da8 : 0x286638
> (0x4631c000 0x10 0x9e38688 0x1)  0x5c063e58 : 0x21dbe5 (0x9e38660
> 0xa0c25a0 0x1fd7e8 0x5d43)  0x5c063e98 : 0x210a86 (0x9e38600 0x0
> 0x93f7fc0 0x9d1fe00)  0x5c063ef8 : 0x216f84 (0x9e38600 0x0 0x0 0x0) 
> 0x5c063f78 : 0x295c57 (0x8d1fb48 0x0 0x0 0x0)  0x5c063fc8 : 0x2a256d
> (0x8d1fb44 0x1 0x10 0xa87aea4)  Kernel Extensions in backtrace (with
> dependencies):  com.apple.GeForce(6.4.0)@0xc5c000->0xd12fff 
> dependency: com.apple.NVDAResman(6.4.0)@0x96e000  dependency:
> com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.2.1)@0x961000  dependency:
> com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.6.5)@0x928000  dependency:
> com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.2.1)@0x93f000 
> com.apple.nvidia.nv50hal(6.4.0)@0x15a2000->0x19b6fff  dependency:
> com.apple.NVDAResman(6.4.0)@0x96e000 
> com.apple.NVDAResman(6.4.0)@0x96e000->0xc5bfff  dependency:
> com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.6.5)@0x928000  dependency:
> com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.2.1)@0x961000  dependency:
> com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.2.1)@0x93f000 
> 
> BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer 
> 
> Mac OS version:  10K549 
> 
> Kernel version:  Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun 7 16:33:36 PDT
> 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386  System model name:
> MacBookPro6,2 (Mac-F22586C8) 
> 
> System uptime in nanoseconds: 108888829816796  unloaded kexts: 
> com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI 4.2.0 (addr 0x142d000, size 0x65536) -
> last unloaded 104100609103  loaded kexts: 
> com.intego.kext.VirusBarrier.AppBarrierKPI    10.6.13 
> com.intego.kext.VirusBarrierKPI   10.6.13 
> com.rim.driver.BlackBerryUSBDriverInt 0.0.64 
> com.apple.filesystems.udf 2.1.1 - last loaded 13212010579854 
> com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor    1.9.3d0 
> com.apple.filesystems.autofs  2.1.0 
> com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver  1.2.0 
> com.apple.driver.AppleHDA 2.0.5f14  com.apple.driver.AGPM 100.12.31 
> com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver 2.0.5f14 
> com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient  3.5.7 
> com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl 1.0.20 
> com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC    1.57 
> com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphics 6.4.0 
> com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphicsFB   6.4.0 
> com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor  3.0.1d2 
> com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X 7.0.0 
> com.apple.driver.AudioIPCDriver   1.1.6 
> com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin  4.7.0a1 
> com.apple.driver.AppleLPC 1.5.1  com.apple.GeForce    6.4.0 
> com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl 2.10.6 
> com.apple.kext.AppleSMCLMU    1.5.2d10 
> com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons    201.6 
> com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard   201.6 
> com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader   2.6.1 
> com.apple.driver.AppleIRController    303.8  com.apple.BootCache  31.1 
> com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib   1.0.0d1 
> com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient    2.6.8 
> com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage    1.6.4 
> com.apple.driver.AirPortBrcm43224 428.42.4 
> com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub  4.2.4 
> com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet  3.0.5b8 
> com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM    1.4.0 
> com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager 160.0.0 
> com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI  4.7.3 
> com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort    2.1.7 
> com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI 4.2.4 
> com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons 1.3.6 
> com.apple.driver.AppleRTC 1.3.1  com.apple.driver.AppleHPET   1.5 
> com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS  1.7  com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC   1.3.6 
> com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC    1.4 
> com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient   142.6.0 
> com.apple.security.sandbox    1  com.apple.security.quarantine    0 
> com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall 2.1.14 
> com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement 142.6.0 
> com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib   2.0.5f14 
> com.apple.driver.AppleProfileReadCounterAction    17 
> com.apple.driver.AppleProfileTimestampAction  10 
> com.apple.driver.AppleProfileThreadInfoAction 14 
> com.apple.driver.AppleProfileRegisterStateAction  10 
> com.apple.driver.AppleProfileKEventAction 10 
> com.apple.driver.AppleProfileCallstackAction  20 
> com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController 1.0.10d0 
> com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP  2.0.3  com.apple.iokit.IOSurface    74.2 
> com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager  2.4.5f3 
> com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily    10.0.3 
> com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily 1.8.3fc2 
> com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib  1.3 
> com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController   2.0.5f14 
> com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily   2.0.5f14 
> com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily    41 
> com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily   4.7.0a1 
> com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI    1.0.10d0 
> com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert 1.0.1 
> com.apple.driver.AppleSMC 3.1.0d5  com.apple.nvidia.nv50hal   6.4.0 
> com.apple.NVDAResman  6.4.0  com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport    2.2.1 
> com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily  2.2.1 
> com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch   207.7 
> com.apple.driver.BroadcomUSBBluetoothHCIController    2.4.5f3 
> com.apple.driver.AppleUSBBluetoothHCIController   2.4.5f3 
> com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily 2.4.5f3 
> com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver    4.2.0 
> com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub 4.2.4 
> com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice    2.6.8 
> com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily 1.6 
> com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily    1.6 
> com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily 1.6.1 
> com.apple.driver.XsanFilter   402.1 
> com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI 1.2.6 
> com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family 320.1 
> com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient   4.2.4 
> com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily    1.10 
> com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily  4.2.6 
> com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily  2.0.6 
> com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime  1.4.0 
> com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily   1.6.6  com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily    1.1 
> com.apple.kext.AppleMatch 1.0.0d1  com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet 6 
> com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass 2.6.7 
> com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite    3.9.0 
> com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice 2.6.8 
> com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily 2.6.8 
> com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily   4.2.4  com.apple.driver.DiskImages  289.1 
> com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily   1.6.3 
> com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform    1.3.6 
> com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily   2.6.5  com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily 1.3.0
```

Comment: This isn't explicitly a GPU panic, but it reaks of one- looking at the backtrace and the corresponding thread. [Given your MBP model, in all likelihood, your GPU has failed](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130933/constant-kernel-panics-since-mavericks-update/130934#130934). You could go through the motions of removing all third party kernel extensions and seeing if it still occurs, but your better off bringing it into your local Apple store for a definitive diagnosis and possible free replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run Apple Hardware test to see if it is your RAM.

It points out to your GeForce, so disable it to test (use only internal graphics for a while).

Comment: Ok will give that a go and get back to you. Thanks