# MacBook Pro random shutdown and restart - with logs

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, shutdown

About 2 or 3 times in a week the computer will shutdown to a grey error screen and reboot. It's very difficult to troubleshoot because it happens so randomly. Most recently, I've gone ahead and copied the logs to include in the post to see what folks here might identify as the problem.

Running OS X 10.9.4 on a Mid-2010 MacBook Pro (Model 6,2).

Any help or suggestions you can kindly provide would go a long way in making my wife happy!

### Console Log

Below is a `system.log` of what was happening around the time shutdown occurred:

```
2014-09-19 9:01:52.615 PM com.apple.IconServicesAgent[490]: IconServicesAgent launched.
2014-09-19 9:01:52.000 PM kernel[0]: considerRebuildOfPrelinkedKernel prebuild rebuild has expired
2014-09-19 9:02:02.664 PM authorizationhost[494]: Failed to authenticate user <saepark> (error: 9).
2014-09-19 9:02:06.261 PM launchservicesd[57]: Application App:"Adobe Reader Updater" asn:0x0-2d02d pid:354 refs=7 @ 0x7fb02a570800 tried to be brought forward, but isn't in fPermittedFrontApps ( ( "LSApplication:0x0-0x38038 pid=488 "SecurityAgent"")), so denying. : LASSession.cp #1481 SetFrontApplication() q=LSSession 100005/0x186a5 queue
2014-09-19 9:02:06.261 PM WindowServer[105]: [cps/setfront] Failed setting the front application to Adobe Reader Updater, psn 0x0-0x2d02d, securitySessionID=0x186a5, err=-13066
2014-09-19 9:02:06.318 PM authexec[495]: executing /bin/chmod
2014-09-19 9:02:06.367 PM authexec[496]: executing /usr/sbin/chown
2014-09-19 9:02:06.491 PM authexec[497]: executing /bin/chmod
2014-09-19 9:02:06.508 PM authexec[498]: executing /usr/sbin/chown
2014-09-19 9:02:06.527 PM authexec[499]: executing /bin/chmod
2014-09-19 9:02:06.545 PM authexec[500]: executing /usr/sbin/chown
2014-09-19 9:02:06.564 PM authexec[501]: executing /bin/chmod
2014-09-19 9:02:06.581 PM authexec[502]: executing /usr/sbin/chown
2014-09-19 9:02:06.600 PM authexec[503]: executing /bin/chmod
2014-09-19 9:02:06.619 PM authexec[504]: executing /usr/sbin/chown
2014-09-19 9:02:06.669 PM authexec[505]: executing /bin/chmod
2014-09-19 9:02:06.720 PM authexec[506]: executing /usr/sbin/chown
2014-09-19 9:02:06.755 PM authexec[507]: executing /tmp/AdobeARM-ebMGO9cvWGg9p61n3z0HJfiuFjc3dbBS/ARMHammer
2014-09-19 9:02:09.114 PM authexec[508]: executing /bin/chmod
2014-09-19 9:02:09.132 PM authexec[509]: executing /usr/sbin/chown
2014-09-19 9:02:09.156 PM authexec[510]: executing /bin/chmod
2014-09-19 9:02:09.174 PM authexec[511]: executing /usr/sbin/chown
2014-09-19 9:02:09.194 PM authexec[512]: executing /bin/chmod
2014-09-19 9:02:09.212 PM authexec[513]: executing /usr/sbin/chown
2014-09-19 9:02:28.879 PM sudo[531]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/private/tmp/PKInstallSandbox.26Dfq4/Scripts/com.adobe.acrobat.a10.AdbeRdrUpd10112.8VEgIj ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/private/tmp/PKInstallSandbox.26Dfq4/Scripts/com.adobe.acrobat.a10.AdbeRdrUpd10112.8VEgIj/Tools/AcroPatchInstall.app/Contents/MacOS/AcroPatchInstall ValidatePath com.adobe.Reader /tmp/com.adobe.reader.updater /Applications/Adobe Reader.app
 2014-09-19 9:02:29.122 PM sudo[534]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/private/tmp/PKInstallSandbox.26Dfq4/Scripts/com.adobe.acrobat.a10.AdbeRdrUpd10112.8VEgIj ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/private/tmp/PKInstallSandbox.26Dfq4/Scripts/com.adobe.acrobat.a10.AdbeRdrUpd10112.8VEgIj/Tools/AcroPatchInstall.app/Contents/MacOS/AcroPatchInstall CheckAppRunning 1 TitleReader /Applications/Adobe Reader.app
2014-09-19 9:03:17.000 PM kernel[0]: Limiting icmp unreach response from 467 to 250 packets per second
2014-09-19 9:03:19.000 PM kernel[0]: Limiting icmp unreach response from 294 to 250 packets per second
2014-09-19 9:05:02.466 PM com.apple.SecurityServer[15]: Killing auth hosts
2014-09-19 9:05:02.466 PM com.apple.SecurityServer[15]: Session 100018 destroyed
2014-09-19 9:05:02.467 PM com.apple.SecurityServer[15]: Killing auth hosts
2014-09-19 9:05:02.467 PM com.apple.SecurityServer[15]: Session 100010 destroyed
2014-09-19 9:07:07.738 PM com.apple.backupd[436]: Finished scan
2014-09-19 9:07:07.741 PM com.apple.backupd[436]: Not using file event preflight for Macintosh HD
2014-09-19 9:07:57.180 PM com.apple.backupd[436]: Found 1554 files (132 MB) needing backup
2014-09-19 9:07:57.228 PM com.apple.backupd[436]: 903.6 MB required (including padding), 1.02 TB available
```

### Error Report

Then, I collected the error report that was prepared to sent to Apple, which I include here:

```
Fri Sep 19 20:51:47 2014
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff7fa17ccf7c): "GPU Panic: [<None>] 5 3 7f 0 0 0 0 3 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00000100: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0xd2000000 0xffffff813bb71000 0x0a5480a2, D0, P3/4\n"@/SourceCache/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.6.22/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:127
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff812970aea0 : 0xffffff801f422f79 
0xffffff812970af20 : 0xffffff7fa17ccf7c 
0xffffff812970aff0 : 0xffffff7f9fee3f1b 
0xffffff812970b0b0 : 0xffffff7f9ffad50a 
0xffffff812970b0f0 : 0xffffff7f9ffad57a 
0xffffff812970b160 : 0xffffff7fa022c056 
0xffffff812970b290 : 0xffffff7f9ffd0ba9 
0xffffff812970b2b0 : 0xffffff7f9feea96d 
0xffffff812970b360 : 0xffffff7f9fee8478 
0xffffff812970b560 : 0xffffff7f9fee9dc7 
0xffffff812970b630 : 0xffffff7fa0dc93df 
0xffffff812970b700 : 0xffffff7fa0df37b3 
0xffffff812970b780 : 0xffffff7fa0ddbae0 
0xffffff812970b7e0 : 0xffffff7fa0ddc3da 
0xffffff812970b830 : 0xffffff7fa0ddc754 
0xffffff812970b8a0 : 0xffffff7fa0ddcfc8 
0xffffff812970b8e0 : 0xffffff7fa0da9fea 
0xffffff812970ba60 : 0xffffff7fa0dd9940 
0xffffff812970bb20 : 0xffffff7fa0da8ad9 
0xffffff812970bb70 : 0xffffff801f8cef16 
0xffffff812970bb90 : 0xffffff801f8d0511 
0xffffff812970bbf0 : 0xffffff801f8cdf7f 
0xffffff812970bd40 : 0xffffff801f4b6998 
0xffffff812970be50 : 0xffffff801f426bc1 
0xffffff812970be80 : 0xffffff801f4139c5 
0xffffff812970bef0 : 0xffffff801f41e013 
0xffffff812970bf70 : 0xffffff801f4c9b8d 
0xffffff812970bfb0 : 0xffffff801f4f3f66 
     Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
        com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.6.22)[32862231-50BC-3AF6-87A2-703321AE4F90]@0xffffff7fa17be000->0xffffff7fa17d1fff
           dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.6.22)[AA46D551-BE0F-33DA-93A3-8F46197BB36F]@0xffffff7fa17b6000
           dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[045D5D6F-AD1E-36DB-A249-A346E2B48E54]@0xffffff7f9fd2b000
           dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[4662B11D-2ECA-315D-875C-618C97CDAB2A]@0xffffff7f9fabe000
           dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[75D81741-64C1-3941-ADFA-9D6B6C434EE4]@0xffffff7f9fe41000
           dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert(1.0.4)[E04639C5-D734-3AB3-A682-FE66694C6653]@0xffffff7fa17b9000
        com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(8.2.4)[D61B2BB9-4289-318D-9197-5E1E13B1FF32]@0xffffff7f9fe94000->0xffffff7fa00fcfff
           dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[4662B11D-2ECA-315D-875C-618C97CDAB2A]@0xffffff7f9fabe000
           dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[D41125CE-69BD-32E7-9B1D-4E83431662DD]@0xffffff7f9fe84000
           dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[75D81741-64C1-3941-ADFA-9D6B6C434EE4]@0xffffff7f9fe41000
        com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla(8.2.4)[B0E6AAA7-E970-3D81-8B43-145D56A3A4AC]@0xffffff7fa0107000->0xffffff7fa03b0fff
           dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(8.2.4)[D61B2BB9-4289-318D-9197-5E1E13B1FF32]@0xffffff7f9fe94000
           dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[4662B11D-2ECA-315D-875C-618C97CDAB2A]@0xffffff7f9fabe000
        com.apple.GeForceTesla(8.2.4)[E0EBC5ED-DC61-3C57-BCCE-0478C0566F4F]@0xffffff7fa0d97000->0xffffff7fa0e61fff
           dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[4662B11D-2ECA-315D-875C-618C97CDAB2A]@0xffffff7f9fabe000
           dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[D41125CE-69BD-32E7-9B1D-4E83431662DD]@0xffffff7f9fe84000
           dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[75D81741-64C1-3941-ADFA-9D6B6C434EE4]@0xffffff7f9fe41000
           dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(8.2.4)[D61B2BB9-4289-318D-9197-5E1E13B1FF32]@0xffffff7f9fe94000
```

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: `WindowServer`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Constant kernel panics since Mavericks update](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130933/constant-kernel-panics-since-mavericks-update)

Comment: It looks like your NVIDA is having problems. Try operating in the non NVIDA mode only for a while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Mid-2010 MBP 6,2*

Given your model, the kernel panic, though incomplete, indicates that your GPU has failed. [This is a known issue for your machine.](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-5681) Your model is subject to a [replacement program](https://support.apple.com/kb/TS4088) for the logicboard due to a defective GPU. It lasts 3 years from the date of purchase. If this is already expired, Apple may or may not still replace your logicboard. It is ultimately at the discretion of the store manager. If you don't qualify, your other option would be [a flat rate repair](http://nwsinglespeed.hubpages.com/hub/Do-You-Know-About-Apples-Flat-Rate-Repair-Pricing), for ~$300. Apple will repair anything wrong with the machine for this fee. Best of luck.

Note: [see my answer here as well.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130933/constant-kernel-panics-since-mavericks-update/130934#130934)