# My MacBook Pro crashed many times

Tags: macbook-pro

Does anyone have any ideas to suggest me? See the Problems report from my MacBook Pro:

```
Anonymous UUID:       3E08FA12-C540-3F53-90F8-44E133699898

Fri Dec 19 08:11:33 2014
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff8016adc43e): Kernel trap at 0xffffff8012a3fba0, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0xffffff8012a3fba0, CR3: 0x000000001950c000, CR4: 0x00000000000206e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0x0000000000000507, RCX: 0x0000000000000001, RDX: 0x0000000000000407
RSP: 0xffffff80ac4e3c38, RBP: 0xffffff80ac4e3c90, RSI: 0x0000000000000507, RDI: 0x0000000000000203
R8:  0xffffff80ac4e3d44, R9:  0x0000000000000002, R10: 0x0000000000000015, R11: 0xffffff80217d8c00
R12: 0xffffff80ac4e3f50, R13: 0xffffff80ac4e3d44, R14: 0x0000000000000001, R15: 0xffffff80170fdbc8
RFL: 0x0000000000010282, RIP: 0xffffff8012a3fba0, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000000
Fault CR2: 0xffffff8012a3fba0, Error code: 0x0000000000000010, Fault CPU: 0x1

Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff80ac4e38c0 : 0xffffff8016a22f79 
0xffffff80ac4e3940 : 0xffffff8016adc43e 
0xffffff80ac4e3b10 : 0xffffff8016af3976 
0xffffff80ac4e3b30 : 0xffffff8012a3fba0 
0xffffff80ac4e3c90 : 0xffffff8016a5d819 
0xffffff80ac4e3cc0 : 0xffffff8016a5dc44 
0xffffff80ac4e3cd0 : 0xffffff8016e3db0e 
0xffffff80ac4e3fb0 : 0xffffff8016ad7607 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
13F34

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Sun Aug 17 19:50:11 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.115.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 9477416E-7BCA-3679-AF97-E1EAAD3DD5A0
Kernel slide:     0x0000000016800000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8016a00000
System model name: MacBookPro6,2 (Mac-F22586C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 76182213391
last loaded kext at 31835835377: com.github.osxfuse.filesystems.osxfusefs   2.7.2 (addr 0xffffff7f98eb0000, size 98304)
loaded kexts:
com.github.osxfuse.filesystems.osxfusefs    2.7.2
com.avg.Antivirus.OnAccess.kext 2015.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.2.7f3
com.apple.driver.AppleTyMCEDriver   1.0.2d2
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.14.34
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   2.6.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.6.3f4
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.13
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphics   8.2.4
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.GeForceTesla  8.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphicsFB 8.2.4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU   4.2.7f3
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.2.7f3
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.6.3f4
com.apple.nvidia.NVDAStartup    8.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.6.22
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.4.11
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.5
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeLZVN 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  325.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.4.1
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.6.7
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    683.4.0
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   700.20.22
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.0.5
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.8.1b2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI   656.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   660.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 217.92.1
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   153
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   217.92.1
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.7
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.6.22
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.6.3f4
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.9.7fc2
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.14
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   91.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.2.7f3
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   8.2.4
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    8.2.4
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.6.3f4
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.6.3f4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.2.7f3
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.7.1d6
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.6.22
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.12d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 240.10
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  660.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.6.7
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   650.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  656.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.6.7
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.6.7
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   640.36
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 660.4.2
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.6.5
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b4
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b5
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 686.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  278.11.1
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 371.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  23
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
Model: MacBookPro6,2, BootROM MBP61.0057.B0F, 2 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.8 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.58f16
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics, Intel HD Graphics, Built-In, 288 MB
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, PCIe, 512 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x802C, 0x384A53463235363634485A2D314731443120
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x802C, 0x384A53463235363634485A2D314731443120
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x93), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.2.7f3 14616, 3 services, 23 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD TS256B, 251 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-898
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: USB Optical Mouse
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Built-in iSight
USB Device: IR Receiver
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Comment: Can you give some details of what exactly happened, for those of us who don't speak Console-ese?

Comment: You have Fuse FS driver, you also have AVG antivirus. No, this Mac is botched. Seriously though try removing them first. In that order.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of a Kernel Panic

- Does this occur in [Safe Mode?](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262)

  - If it does, skip uninstallation mentioned next and see the comments below.
  - If it does not, then uninstall the software associated with these kernel extensions

> com.github.osxfuse.filesystems.osxfusefs
>   com.avg.Antivirus.OnAccess.kext

Do so *according to the developer’s instructions*. Often times, third party kernel extensions can cause kernel panics.

---

> Model: MacBookPro6,2

**[This is a known issue for your machine. See my answer here for more details.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130933/constant-kernel-panics-since-mavericks-update/130934#130934)**

- If the panics persist without any third party drivers, then it’s a hardware problem.
- If other panics include “type...GPU Panic” along with nvidia dependencies in the backtrace, then it’s a hardware problem.

Best of luck.