# MacBook Pro keeps shutting down with no visible pattern

Tags: macbook-pro, kernel-panic

I've exhausted all the things I could imagine trying to solve my problem but unfortunately nothing helped.
This is the 40th time today that my MacBook Pro suffers a kernel panic and then shuts down. I can't get my MacBook up more than 2-5 min.
I've read everything about kernel panics and tried many different solutions but not one single change in this problem.
I've stoped using all applications that consume the most CPU, RAM and Graphic Memory like Google Chrome, Adobe illustrator, Photoshop but it only relieves for a couple of hours and then the continuous shut downs come back again.
I have 8Gb of RAM and installed Memory Cleaner and only work with minimum of 4GB of RAM Free but it keeps shutting down.
I opened my Mac and cleaned the fans from dust.
I've tried many different reboots.

This are the specs of my MacBook Pro:

```
 Model Name:    MacBook Pro
 Model Identifier:  MacBookPro6,2
 Processor Name:    Intel Core i7
 Processor Speed:   2,66 GHz
 Number of Processors:  1
 Total Number of Cores: 2
 L2 Cache (per Core):   256 KB
 L3 Cache:  4 MB
 Memory:    8 GB
 Processor Interconnect Speed:  4.8 GT/s
 Boot ROM Version:  MBP61.0057.B0F
 SMC Version (system):  1.58f17
 Sudden Motion Sensor:
 State: Enabled
```

This is the last kernel panic report I've received:

```
Anonymous UUID:       755CDD8F-295C-EDD1-A2E0-6B4B8F052CA3

Sun Dec 28 14:39:28 2014

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff7f9595ef63): "GPU Panic: [<None>] 3 3 7f 0 0 0 0 3 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00000100: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0xd2000000 0xffffff812e58e000 0x0a5480a2, D0, P2/4\n"@/SourceCache/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.7.21/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:127
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff811d443680 : 0xffffff8012d3a811 
0xffffff811d443700 : 0xffffff7f9595ef63 
0xffffff811d4437e0 : 0xffffff7f938c2b9f 
0xffffff811d4438a0 : 0xffffff7f9398c18e 
0xffffff811d4438e0 : 0xffffff7f9398c1fe 
0xffffff811d443950 : 0xffffff7f93c0b056 
0xffffff811d443a80 : 0xffffff7f939af82d 
0xffffff811d443aa0 : 0xffffff7f938c95f1 
0xffffff811d443b50 : 0xffffff7f938c70fc 
0xffffff811d443d50 : 0xffffff7f938c819c 
0xffffff811d443e30 : 0xffffff7f93874f5e 
0xffffff811d443e90 : 0xffffff7f9592fdf6 
0xffffff811d443ee0 : 0xffffff7f9592eab0 
0xffffff811d443f00 : 0xffffff8012d6be13 
0xffffff811d443fb0 : 0xffffff8012e192c7 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0)[796AE430-39FB-3255-8161-D52AFA28EE2B]@0xffffff7f93872000->0xffffff7f93adbfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[766FC23F-452C-3B74-951C-598BB17BCF06]@0xffffff7f93524000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[F4738C55-B507-3627-A9CA-3D29A5230A03]@0xffffff7f93862000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[6D99A3BE-D531-3780-880B-13F2FC894A4A]@0xffffff7f9381b000
         com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla(10.0)[7FE40648-F15F-3E18-91E2-FDDDF4CDA355]@0xffffff7f93ae6000->0xffffff7f93d8ffff
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0.0)[796AE430-39FB-3255-8161-D52AFA28EE2B]@0xffffff7f93872000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[766FC23F-452C-3B74-951C-598BB17BCF06]@0xffffff7f93524000
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.7.21)[32B7E2DE-1F9D-3555-B687-7A76A62B81D2]@0xffffff7f95950000->0xffffff7f95963fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.7.21)[62689710-EEA7-307A-AC83-B8F25DA88A6A]@0xffffff7f95948000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[70E2B65E-A91A-3522-A1A0-79FD63EABB4C]@0xffffff7f937a9000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[766FC23F-452C-3B74-951C-598BB17BCF06]@0xffffff7f93524000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[6D99A3BE-D531-3780-880B-13F2FC894A4A]@0xffffff7f9381b000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert(1.1.0)[0183904C-6A16-32C4-9405-EEFD7F820B02]@0xffffff7f9594b000
         com.apple.driver.AGPM(100.14.37)[1A6EDBFD-5D0A-3734-8D20-CDBD58DA6B63]@0xffffff7f9592d000->0xffffff7f9593ffff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[766FC23F-452C-3B74-951C-598BB17BCF06]@0xffffff7f93524000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily(5.8.0d49)[55A20B1B-EC55-33F7-ADD5-549F8C738A86]@0xffffff7f9431b000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[F4738C55-B507-3627-A9CA-3D29A5230A03]@0xffffff7f93862000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[6D99A3BE-D531-3780-880B-13F2FC894A4A]@0xffffff7f9381b000
            dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(3.7.21)[4700601D-3FEB-3B86-B2BA-8D71AF84D1C4]@0xffffff7f95927000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
14B25

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0: Fri Sep 19 00:26:44 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2782.1.97~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 89E10306-BC78-3A3B-955C-7C4922577E61
Kernel slide:     0x0000000012a00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8012c00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8012b00000
System model name: MacBookPro6,2 (Mac-F22586C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 1045360291873
last loaded kext at 90320971006: org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp 4.3.20 (addr 0xffffff7f95acd000, size 28672)
last unloaded kext at 181481079717: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI   656.4.1 (addr 0xffffff7f9410f000, size 65536)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  4.3.20
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  4.3.20
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 4.3.20
com.tuxera.filesystems.tufsfs.fusefs_txantfs    2013.3.14
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 4.3.20
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.14.37
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.1f2
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   267.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   267.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphics   10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphicsFB 10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.7.21
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.GeForceTesla  10.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.10
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.1f2
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.5.0
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.0
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.6.5
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.20.24
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.2b3
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.0.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.7.21
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard  175.5
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.3.1f2
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   175.5
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 267.0
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   200.6
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.7.21
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 267.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 267.0
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    10.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.1f2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.1f2
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.8.0d49
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 245.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaComm
```

I need to know what is causing all this kernel panics and how to stop them. At this moment, I can't work anymore while my Mac is reacting like this.

Comment: [The panic report indicates a defective GPU, which is a known issue for this model. See my answer here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130933/constant-kernel-panics-since-mavericks-update/130934#130934).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your model has a known issue with the graphics cards and was under a [Quality Program that has now ended](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203554). Review the other kernel panic logs, as the one you posted shows that it suffered a `GPU Panic` in that instance. Chances are that it's a hardware issue with the graphics card and you will need to run through Apple or Authorized Service Provider for a fix.

Answer (score 0):

To see if it is internal component that is overheating try to instal iStat Pro widget and look at temperature on CPU and GPU.

[iStat Pro Widget](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Dashboard-Widgets/Status-Info/iStat-pro.shtml)