# Random Restarts, GPU Panic

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, gpu

As of today, my 15" 2010 Macbook Pro has randomly rebooted twice within an hour. I'm including the Panic Report that was displayed after the computer rebooted.

I'm running OS X 10.10.2, connected to an external monitor via mini display port to VGA adapter, and I was using these applications when the reboots occurred:

- firefox
- vlc
- skype
- finder

My questions are: What's causing the problem? and what should I do to prevent this from ever happening again?

```
Anonymous UUID:       3A85DED9-ED42-183E-F7F9-5CA2F73533B7

Thu Mar  5 17:55:09 2015

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff7f8ae39f63): "GPU Panic: [<None>] 3 3 7f 0 0 0 0 3 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00000100: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0xd2000000 0xffffff80afad2000 0x0a5480a2, D0, P2/4\n"@/SourceCache/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.8.6/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:127
Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff809d9eb0f0 : 0xffffff800812fe41 
0xffffff809d9eb170 : 0xffffff7f8ae39f63 
0xffffff809d9eb250 : 0xffffff7f88d52b9f 
0xffffff809d9eb310 : 0xffffff7f88e1c18e 
0xffffff809d9eb350 : 0xffffff7f88e1c1fe 
0xffffff809d9eb3c0 : 0xffffff7f8909b056 
0xffffff809d9eb4f0 : 0xffffff7f88e3f82d 
0xffffff809d9eb510 : 0xffffff7f88d595f1 
0xffffff809d9eb5c0 : 0xffffff7f88d570fc 
0xffffff809d9eb7c0 : 0xffffff7f88d5807a 
0xffffff809d9eb8a0 : 0xffffff7f8a3ef446 
0xffffff809d9eb8e0 : 0xffffff7f8a3fedff 
0xffffff809d9eb900 : 0xffffff7f8a42d493 
0xffffff809d9eb930 : 0xffffff7f8a42d4ed 
0xffffff809d9eb970 : 0xffffff7f8a404a1f 
0xffffff809d9eb9c0 : 0xffffff7f8a3cf027 

0xffffff809d9eba60 : 0xffffff7f8a3cada1 
0xffffff809d9eba90 : 0xffffff7f8a3c8873 
0xffffff809d9ebad0 : 0xffffff80086ff00c 
0xffffff809d9ebb60 : 0xffffff8008701163 
0xffffff809d9ebbc0 : 0xffffff80086fe9c3 
0xffffff809d9ebd00 : 0xffffff80081e4a87 
0xffffff809d9ebe10 : 0xffffff8008133f8c 
0xffffff809d9ebe40 : 0xffffff8008118a93 
0xffffff809d9ebe90 : 0xffffff80081293bd 
0xffffff809d9ebf10 : 0xffffff80082059fa 
0xffffff809d9ebfb0 : 0xffffff8008236ea6 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0)[796AE430-39FB-3255-8161-D52AFA28EE2B]@0xffffff7f88d02000->0xffffff7f88f6bfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[56AD16B5-4F29-3F74-93E7-D492B3966DE2]@0xffffff7f889b0000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[E5A48E71-70F5-3B01-81D3-C2B037BBE80A]@0xffffff7f88cf2000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[619F6C9F-0461-3BA1-A75F-53BB0F87ACD3]@0xffffff7f88cab000
         com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla(10.0)[7FE40648-F15F-3E18-91E2-FDDDF4CDA355]@0xffffff7f88f76000->0xffffff7f8921ffff
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0.0)[796AE430-39FB-3255-8161-D52AFA28EE2B]@0xffffff7f88d02000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[56AD16B5-4F29-3F74-93E7-D492B3966DE2]@0xffffff7f889b0000
         com.apple.GeForceTesla(10.0)[3EA67900-B4A9-30BB-964D-0904DA5421CC]@0xffffff7f8a3ac000->0xffffff7f8a479fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[56AD16B5-4F29-3F74-93E7-D492B3966DE2]@0xffffff7f889b0000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[E5A48E71-70F5-3B01-81D3-C2B037BBE80A]@0xffffff7f88cf2000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[619F6C9F-0461-3BA1-A75F-53BB0F87ACD3]@0xffffff7f88cab000
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0.0)[796AE430-39FB-3255-8161-D52AFA28EE2B]@0xffffff7f88d02000
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.8.6)[BE610379-FAEA-3E8F-B6AF-F92B70B3C5CD]@0xffffff7f8ae2b000->0xffffff7f8ae3efff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.8.6)[76B001B1-30F1-3D72-B264-85D77B254C2F]@0xffffff7f8ae23000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[70E2B65E-A91A-3522-A1A0-79FD63EABB4C]@0xffffff7f88c35000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[56AD16B5-4F29-3F74-93E7-D492B3966DE2]@0xffffff7f889b0000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[619F6C9F-0461-3BA1-A75F-53BB0F87ACD3]@0xffffff7f88cab000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert(1.1.0)[42706EB3-1447-3931-A668-FBAC58AAAA7A]@0xffffff7f8ae26000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer
Boot args: niog=1

Mac OS version:
14C109

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.1.0: Mon Dec 22 23:10:38 PST 2014; root:xnu-2782.10.72~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: DCF5C2D5-16AE-37F5-B2BE-ED127048DFF5
Kernel slide:     0x0000000007e00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8008000000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8007f00000
System model name: MacBookPro6,2 (Mac-F22586C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 312912210139
last loaded kext at 85034189912: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC   4.2.2b5 (addr 0xffffff7f895ed000, size 24576)
last unloaded kext at 203156395563: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI   656.4.1 (addr 0xffffff7f89575000, size 65536)
loaded kexts:
com.symantec.kext.SymAPComm 100.1f2
com.symantec.kext.ips   3.5.1f2
com.symantec.kext.ndcengine 1.0f2
com.symantec.kext.internetSecurity  5.2.1f2
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.15.5
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.2f6
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   269.25
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   269.25
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.7d0
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.8.6
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.GeForceTesla  10.0.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.2f6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.11
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphics   10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphicsFB 10.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.5.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.3
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.7.0
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.20.24
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.2
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.0
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.8.6
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 269.25
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.8.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.2f6
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.8.1d38
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 269.25
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 269.25
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   203.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   10.0.0
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.2f6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 245.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.3
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.7.1
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471.10.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.3
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.3
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   710.55
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.6
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 710.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 396
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
Model: MacBookPro6,2, BootROM MBP61.0057.B0F, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.4 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.58f16
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics, Intel HD Graphics, Built-In, 288 MB
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, PCIe, 256 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353637334648302D4346382020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353637334648302D4346382020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x93), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.24)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.2f6 15235, 3 services, 19 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Serial ATA Device: KINGSTON SH100S3120G, 120.03 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-898
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Dell USB Keyboard Hub
USB Device: USB Optical Mouse
USB Device: Dell USB Keyboard Hub
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Ext HDD 1021
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: Built-in iSight
Thunderbolt Bus: 









Anonymous UUID:       3A85DED9-ED42-183E-F7F9-5CA2F73533B7

Thu Mar  5 19:02:10 2015

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff7f8d839f63): "GPU Panic: [<None>] 3 3 7f 0 0 0 0 3 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00000100: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0xd2000000 0xffffff80b22e2000 0x0a5480a2, D0, P2/4\n"@/SourceCache/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.8.6/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:127
Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff80a0bbb0f0 : 0xffffff800ab2fe41 
0xffffff80a0bbb170 : 0xffffff7f8d839f63 
0xffffff80a0bbb250 : 0xffffff7f8b752b9f 
0xffffff80a0bbb310 : 0xffffff7f8b81c18e 
0xffffff80a0bbb350 : 0xffffff7f8b81c1fe 
0xffffff80a0bbb3c0 : 0xffffff7f8ba9b056 
0xffffff80a0bbb4f0 : 0xffffff7f8b83f82d 
0xffffff80a0bbb510 : 0xffffff7f8b7595f1 
0xffffff80a0bbb5c0 : 0xffffff7f8b7570fc 
0xffffff80a0bbb7c0 : 0xffffff7f8b75807a 
0xffffff80a0bbb8a0 : 0xffffff7f8cdef446 
0xffffff80a0bbb8e0 : 0xffffff7f8cdfedff 
0xffffff80a0bbb900 : 0xffffff7f8ce2d493 
0xffffff80a0bbb930 : 0xffffff7f8ce2d4ed 
0xffffff80a0bbb970 : 0xffffff7f8ce04a1f 
0xffffff80a0bbb9c0 : 0xffffff7f8cdcf027 
0xffffff80a0bbba60 : 0xffffff7f8cdcada1 
0xffffff80a0bbba90 : 0xffffff7f8cdc8873 
0xffffff80a0bbbad0 : 0xffffff800b0ff00c 
0xffffff80a0bbbb60 : 0xffffff800b101163 
0xffffff80a0bbbbc0 : 0xffffff800b0fe9c3 
0xffffff80a0bbbd00 : 0xffffff800abe4a87 
0xffffff80a0bbbe10 : 0xffffff800ab33f8c 
0xffffff80a0bbbe40 : 0xffffff800ab18a93 
0xffffff80a0bbbe90 : 0xffffff800ab293bd 
0xffffff80a0bbbf10 : 0xffffff800ac059fa 
0xffffff80a0bbbfb0 : 0xffffff800ac36ea6 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.8.6)[BE610379-FAEA-3E8F-B6AF-F92B70B3C5CD]@0xffffff7f8d82b000->0xffffff7f8d83efff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.8.6)[76B001B1-30F1-3D72-B264-85D77B254C2F]@0xffffff7f8d823000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[70E2B65E-A91A-3522-A1A0-79FD63EABB4C]@0xffffff7f8b635000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[56AD16B5-4F29-3F74-93E7-D492B3966DE2]@0xffffff7f8b3b0000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[619F6C9F-0461-3BA1-A75F-53BB0F87ACD3]@0xffffff7f8b6ab000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert(1.1.0)[42706EB3-1447-3931-A668-FBAC58AAAA7A]@0xffffff7f8d826000
         com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0)[796AE430-39FB-3255-8161-D52AFA28EE2B]@0xffffff7f8b702000->0xffffff7f8b96bfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[56AD16B5-4F29-3F74-93E7-D492B3966DE2]@0xffffff7f8b3b0000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[E5A48E71-70F5-3B01-81D3-C2B037BBE80A]@0xffffff7f8b6f2000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[619F6C9F-0461-3BA1-A75F-53BB0F87ACD3]@0xffffff7f8b6ab000
         com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla(10.0)[7FE40648-F15F-3E18-91E2-FDDDF4CDA355]@0xffffff7f8b976000->0xffffff7f8bc1ffff
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0.0)[796AE430-39FB-3255-8161-D52AFA28EE2B]@0xffffff7f8b702000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[56AD16B5-4F29-3F74-93E7-D492B3966DE2]@0xffffff7f8b3b0000
         com.apple.GeForceTesla(10.0)[3EA67900-B4A9-30BB-964D-0904DA5421CC]@0xffffff7f8cdac000->0xffffff7f8ce79fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[56AD16B5-4F29-3F74-93E7-D492B3966DE2]@0xffffff7f8b3b0000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[E5A48E71-70F5-3B01-81D3-C2B037BBE80A]@0xffffff7f8b6f2000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[619F6C9F-0461-3BA1-A75F-53BB0F87ACD3]@0xffffff7f8b6ab000
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0.0)[796AE430-39FB-3255-8161-D52AFA28EE2B]@0xffffff7f8b702000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer
Boot args: niog=1

Mac OS version:
14C109

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.1.0: Mon Dec 22 23:10:38 PST 2014; root:xnu-2782.10.72~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: DCF5C2D5-16AE-37F5-B2BE-ED127048DFF5
Kernel slide:     0x000000000a800000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff800aa00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff800a900000
System model name: MacBookPro6,2 (Mac-F22586C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 3829319326607
last loaded kext at 11866509383: com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC 1.70 (addr 0xffffff7f8d09b000, size 32768)
last unloaded kext at 153618161860: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI   656.4.1 (addr 0xffffff7f8bf75000, size 65536)
loaded kexts:
com.symantec.kext.SymAPComm 100.1f2
com.symantec.kext.ips   3.5.1f2
com.symantec.kext.ndcengine 1.0f2
com.symantec.kext.internetSecurity  5.2.1f2
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.15.5
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.2f6
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   269.25
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.GeForceTesla  10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   269.25
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.8.6
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.11
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.7d0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.2f6
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphics   10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphicsFB 10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.5.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.3
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.7.0
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.20.24
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.2
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.0
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.8.6
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   10.0.0
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    10.0.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 269.25
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.8.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.2f6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.2f6
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 269.25
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 269.25
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   203.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.8.1d38
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 245.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.3
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.7.1
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471.10.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.3
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.3
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   710.55
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.6
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 710.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 396
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
Model: MacBookPro6,2, BootROM MBP61.0057.B0F, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.4 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.58f16
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics, Intel HD Graphics, Built-In, 288 MB
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, PCIe, 256 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353637334648302D4346382020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353637334648302D4346382020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x93), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.24)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.2f6 15235, 3 services, 19 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Serial ATA Device: KINGSTON SH100S3120G, 120.03 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-898
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Dell USB Keyboard Hub
USB Device: USB Optical Mouse
USB Device: Dell USB Keyboard Hub
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: Built-in iSight
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the computer without the attached monitor for a while?

Comment: I agree with @Buscar웃 that you should first uninstall Norton, just to rule it out as a culprit. I can say with a high degree of confidence that it’s a faulty GPU though - see my answer here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/130934/62132

Comment: Before spending a lots of money on new GPU, just disable the Norton and see if the problem goes away. You could run the Apple Hardware test, or run in safe mode to double check. Furthermore you could reset your NVRAM (PRAM). Why Norton? it is known fact that it does interfere with OS X operations. Normally if it is a hardware problem (GPU) it wont be sporadic.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by njboot [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/130934/62132)
this is (very likely) a known issue with 15" 2010 Macbook Pro's. I experienced the same problem with my own 15" 2010 Macbook Pro about a year ago.

I recommend that you back up all and any important data as soon as possible (if you haven't already), and take your computer into an Apple store to be examined. Depending on what region of the world you are in, you *might* be able to get the malfunctioning parts replaced for free, or get it repaired (at the cost of the parts and labor).

See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203554
for the (recently ended) free replacement program for 2010 models
As well as http://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/
Although it pertains to the newer 2011 models, the 2010 page carried the same information before the program was ended.