# Black screen Macbookpro Mid 2010

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, error

I have a problem with my macbook pro mid 2010.
When am working, screen become black , but the computer is not shutdown.
I force restart with the bouton and i have a error message.
Can you help me to analyse the report ? I think it's a GPU but, i'm not sure.
The BSD process name in this report is WindowsServer, but is not always the same (kernel_task, other...)
I have done a SMC and NVRAM reset, and a memory test i don't have error.
But i have the same problem
Thanks you

```
Interval Since Last Panic Report:  208659 sec
Panics Since Last Report:          9
Anonymous UUID:                    8EE3028C-CC92-4E54-8CED-A982BC2F8B7A

Thu Jan 26 17:48:48 2017
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff7f80966007): NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00000100: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0xd2000000 0xffffff809fa2f000 0x0a5480a2, D0, P3/4
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff807bbc2e10 : 0xffffff8000220792
0xffffff807bbc2e90 : 0xffffff7f80966007
0xffffff807bbc2f20 : 0xffffff7f80a5eb83
0xffffff807bbc2f80 : 0xffffff7f80a5ebf7
0xffffff807bbc2ff0 : 0xffffff7f80d60855
0xffffff807bbc3130 : 0xffffff7f80a82ddd
0xffffff807bbc3160 : 0xffffff7f8096fd6a
0xffffff807bbc3210 : 0xffffff7f8096b43c
0xffffff807bbc3400 : 0xffffff7f8096c668
0xffffff807bbc34d0 : 0xffffff7f81e7da92
0xffffff807bbc35b0 : 0xffffff7f81e81850
0xffffff807bbc3620 : 0xffffff7f81e81c6e
0xffffff807bbc36b0 : 0xffffff7f81e8231f
0xffffff807bbc37d0 : 0xffffff7f81e7de7e
0xffffff807bbc38f0 : 0xffffff7f81e9f6ea
0xffffff807bbc3930 : 0xffffff7f81e9fb1a
0xffffff807bbc3950 : 0xffffff7f81eb3ba7
0xffffff807bbc3ac0 : 0xffffff7f81eb3d88
0xffffff807bbc3b10 : 0xffffff7f81eb4938
0xffffff807bbc3b50 : 0xffffff7f81ea921c
0xffffff807bbc3b80 : 0xffffff7f81e8a8ca
0xffffff807bbc3bc0 : 0xffffff8000655575
0xffffff807bbc3be0 : 0xffffff8000656838
0xffffff807bbc3c40 : 0xffffff8000656fbb
0xffffff807bbc3d80 : 0xffffff80002a3f08
0xffffff807bbc3e80 : 0xffffff8000223096
0xffffff807bbc3eb0 : 0xffffff80002148a9
0xffffff807bbc3f10 : 0xffffff800021bbd8
0xffffff807bbc3f70 : 0xffffff80002aef10
0xffffff807bbc3fb0 : 0xffffff80002daec3
     Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
        com.apple.NVDAResman(7.3.2)[97284661-2629-379E-B86B-D388618E8C30]@0xffffff7f808 ff000->0xffffff7f80bfafff
           dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.7)[5C23D598-58B2-3204-BC03-BC3C0F00BD32]@0xffffff 7f80889000
           dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.3.4)[7C8672C4-8B0D-3CCF-A79A-23C62E90F895]@0xff ffff7f808ed000
           dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.4)[D0A1F6BD-E66E-3DD8-9913-A3AB8746F422]@0 xffffff7f808b4000
        com.apple.nvidia.nv50hal(7.3.2)[38ACBB3D-4E3C-3883-9A4B-67F15592905F]@0xffffff7 f80bfb000->0xffffff7f80f1dfff
           dependency: com.apple.NVDAResman(7.3.2)[97284661-2629-379E-B86B-D388618E8C30]@0xffffff7f808 ff000
           dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.7)[5C23D598-58B2-3204-BC03-BC3C0F00BD32]@0xffffff 7f80889000
        com.apple.GeForce(7.3.2)[7E1D7726-416F-3716-ACCB-E1E276E35002]@0xffffff7f81e470 00->0xffffff7f81f09fff
           dependency: com.apple.NVDAResman(7.3.2)[97284661-2629-379E-B86B-D388618E8C30]@0xffffff7f808 ff000
           dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.3.4)[7C8672C4-8B0D-3CCF-A79A-23C62E90F895]@0xff ffff7f808ed000
           dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.7)[5C23D598-58B2-3204-BC03-BC3C0F00BD32]@0xffffff 7f80889000
           dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.4)[D0A1F6BD-E66E-3DD8-9913-A3AB8746F422]@0 xffffff7f808b4000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer

Mac OS version:
11G63

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.2: Thu Aug 23 16:25:48 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.32.7~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: FF3BB088-60A4-349C-92EA-CA649C698CE5
System model name: MacBookPro6,2 (Mac-F22586C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 16870228814769
last loaded kext at 16232839721790: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC 4.1.22 (addr 0xffffff7f807ca000, size 16384)
last unloaded kext at 16304863684475: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs 1.7.1 (addr 0xffffff7f8154a000, size 49152)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 1.7.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor 1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver 122
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA 2.2.5a5
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient 3.5.9
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver 2.2.5a5
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC 1.59
com.apple.driver.AGPM 100.12.75
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphics 7.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphicsFB 7.3.2
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor 3.0.2d6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC 5.0.0d8
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet 1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager 4.0.8f17
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X 7.0.0
com.apple.GeForce 7.3.2
com.apple.driver.AudioIPCDriver 1.2.3
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU 2.0.1d2
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl 3.1.33
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.1.33
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin 5.0.0d8
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC 1.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl 1.0.33
com.apple.filesystems.autofs 3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons 227.6
com.apple.driver.BroadcomUSBBluetoothHCIController 4.0.8f17
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 227.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController 312
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.0.6
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient 3.2.1
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI 2.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage 2.1.0
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 33
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI 4.9.0
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331 561.7.22
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet 3.2.4b8
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub 5.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM 1.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager 161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort 2.3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons 1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI 5.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC 1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET 1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS 1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC 1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC 1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 195.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall 3.2.30
com.apple.security.quarantine 1.4
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet 8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement 195.0.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.2.5a5
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP 2.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface 80.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily 10.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily 1.8.6fc18
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib 1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.2.5a5
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.2.5a5
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl 3.1.33
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC 3.1.3d10
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 5.0.0d8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI 1.0.10d0
com.apple.nvidia.nv50hal 7.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert 1.0.4
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.1.1d6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController 1.0.10d0
com.apple.NVDAResman 7.3.2
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport 2.3.4
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily 2.3.4
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBBluetoothHCIController 4.0.8f17
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily 4.0.8f17
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 230.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver 5.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice 3.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass 3.0.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub 5.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite 5.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice 3.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily 1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily 1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily 1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily 3.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily 4.4.8
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family 420.3
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.1b1
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 5.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily 2.0.8
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime 1.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 5.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily 1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox 177.11
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 331.7
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.7.2
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore 28.18
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform 1.5
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.7
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily 1.4
Model: MacBookPro6,2, BootROM MBP61.0057.B0F, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.4 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.58f16
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, PCIe, 256 MB
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics, Intel HD Graphics, Built-In, 288 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353637334648302D4346382020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353637334648302D4346382020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x93), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.198.19.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.0.8f17, 2 service, 11 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Serial ATA Device: HGST HTS721010A9E630, 1 TB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-898
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514, 0xfa100000 / 2
USB Device: Elements 1078, 0x1058  (Western Digital Technologies, Inc.), 0x1078, 0xfa140000 / 6
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 5
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x8218, 0xfa113000 / 9
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0237, 0xfa120000 / 4
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader, apple_vendor_id, 0x8403, 0xfa130000 / 3
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: Built-in iSight, apple_vendor_id, 0x8507, 0xfd110000 / 4
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0xfd120000 / 3
```

Comment: It's not the same GPU Panic as here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130933/constant-kernel-gpu-panics-gpupanic-cpp127 but can you try to prevent switching to nVidia graphics? I had the same model and this fixed my problems...

Comment: Thanks you for your replies, prevent switching with gfxcardstatus ?

Comment: Yes this is the app that helped me

Comment: I test this way : launch System Preferences, choose Energy Saver, and disable the Automatic Graphics Switching option. This causes the MacBook to always run high-performance graphics, which will affect battery life.

Comment: But this will use nVidia graphics instead of the Intel. I had to work on the Intel in order to not crash the machine. Anyway, worth the try, maybe the card switching causes the problem...

Comment: Do you have the black screen *with a mouse cursor* when you boot?